Newtonian potential on hyperplane smooth up to boundary?
Let $\rho:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be smooth and of compact support. We define the newton potential $$u(x,y,z) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \rho(s_1,s_2) \frac{1}{\|(x,y,z) - (s_1,s_2,0) \|} ds_1 ds_2. $$ I.e., this is the electric potential where the plane $z=0$ has density $\rho$.
It is well known that $u$ is smooth on the halfspace $z>0$ and continuous on the whole space $\mathbb{R}^3$. I want to know whether it is smooth on the closed halfspace $z \geq 0$.
Presumably, after taking high order partial derivatives under the integral sign, the integral does not converge for $z=0$. So perhaps the partial derivatives are given by some continuous extension?
